# SQLite regular expression with LIKE

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

Hello I have a table with the next rows:

```
Path    
-------------------                   
Archive.zip                
MyFile.zip                 
MyFolder                   
MyFolder/myfiledata.txt    
MyFolder/otherfile.dat     
OtherFolder
OtherFolder/otherfile.dat  
OtherFolder/More/filenext.dat  
OtherFolder/Less/filenext.dat
```

And I want use like, to get, only first level:

```
Path
-------------------                       
Archive.zip                
MyFile.zip                 
MyFolder                   
OtherFolder
```

What will be the query with SQLite?

Thanks!

Comment: To be pedantic -- `LIKE` does *not* use or support regex syntax; sqlite has a separate `REGEX` operator if you really wanted regular expressions, which you don't actually want or need here. `LIKE` is effectively (almost) a case-insensitive version of `GLOB` which uses `%` rather than the traditional UNIX `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need something like that:

```
SELECT Path FROM PathTable WHERE Path NOT LIKE '%/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easiest to think in terms of what you might do to SELECT the inverse.

```
SELECT Path from YourTable WHERE NOT (Path LIKE '%/%')
```